# I need to replace the second occurrence of string1 by string2 on every line - vim

Tags: vim, substitution

I know that there are multiple occurrences of string1 in every line of the file. I am looking for the shortest/quickest way to replace the second one by string2. Any method will do though vim is my preference.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the second occurrence of "string1" using `\zs`.

Based on the `:h \zs` example, it will be

```
:%s/\(.\{-}\zsstring1\)\{2}/string2
```

It'll be more straightforward using external `sed` in Vim command mode

```
:%!sed 's/string1/string2/2'
```

See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/substitute-second-occurence-on-line for more ways to accomplish it.

Comment: Thank you leaf, Your sed suggestion is exactly what I needed. Goes to show that for every problem there is a tool that does the job best. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
:%normal 0/string1^Mncgnstring2<CR>
```

Breakdown:

- `:[range]normal <macro>` executes normal mode `<macro>` on every line in `[range]`,
- `%` is a shorthand for range `[<first line>,<last line>]`, which covers every line in the buffer,
- `0` is the first command of our macro, it places the cursor on the first column of the line, which is a good habit to  have,
- `/string1^M` moves the cursor to the first match for `string1`, the `^M` is a literal `<CR>` obtained with `<C-v><CR>`,
- `n` moves the cursor to to the next match,
- `cgnstring2` changes the current match to `string2`.

See `:help :range`, `:help :normal`, `:help gn`.

---

But it would have been more interesting to see what you tried and fix it, rather than provide you with a working solution.

Comment: Thanks romainl for your answer. Shouldn't your command end in ESC rather than CR? For some reason the code doesn't work when used directly in command line. But when I put 0/string1|^Mcgnstring2^[<80><fd>aj (which is a recorded macro) in a register (say h) and run the macro as :%norm @h from the command line then it works fine.

Comment: I tested it before submitting the answer.